# Stop AWK from replacing tabs with spaces

Tags: awk

I am trying to modify the first character of each line in a file separated by both spaces and tabs.

In the following example the first 3 spaces are tabs and the following two spaces are spaces.

```
cat example.gtf
1      havana  gene    11896 14409 .
1      havana  gene    12613 12227 .
```

I want to prepend an `m` to the first value in each row as in the following... desired output.gtf.  This can be achieved with `awk '$1="m"$1' example.gtf > desiredOutput.gtf`

```
cat desiredOutput.gtf
m1      havana  gene    11896 14409 .
m1      havana  gene    12613 12227 .
```

However, awk replaces the first three tabs with spaces, corrupting the format of the output file.  How can I prevent awk from changing tabs to spaces?

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat file
1       havana  gene    11896 14409 .
1       havana  gene    12613 12227 .
```

In decreasing order of simplicity, clarity, and performance:

```
$ awk '{print "m"$0}' file
m1      havana  gene    11896 14409 .
m1      havana  gene    12613 12227 .

$ awk '{$0="m"$0} 1' file
m1      havana  gene    11896 14409 .
m1      havana  gene    12613 12227 .

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} {$1="m"$1} 1' file
m1      havana  gene    11896 14409 .
m1      havana  gene    12613 12227 .
```

Comment: Found this way to use FS OFS, not sure how compatible it is.  `awk '{$1="m"$1} 1' {O,}FS="\t" file`

Comment: @Jotne I feel it unnecessarily obfuscates the code when any variables are set in a section of code **after**  they are used so I always set FS or OFS before the body of the script (either by `-v` or in `BEGIN{}`) unless I **have** to set them to different values before processing different input files. I hate reading a script assuming FS and OFS have their default value and then getting to the end and discovering they were set to something else all along. Grrr.... In a perfect world `FS` would have been named `IFS` and using `-F` would set both variables but that ship sailed 30+ years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Simple `SED`

```
sed 's/^/m/g' file
m1      havana  gene    11896 14409 .
m1      havana  gene    12613 12227 .
```